# how to perform online editing of an asp.net mvc site like sharepoint site

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have a requirement in which i need to edit a live asp.net mvc site, same like a sharepoint site.
In sharepoint i have an edit option where the content will be displayed in HTML Form, where i can change the content and save it.

In same manner i need to do it on an asp.net mvc site.
is there any option accross to do this?

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you want to edit but the answer is yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty normal situation, you just want to have the content stored in a database instead of hard coded on the page.  You would then setup the MVC Controller to read the database values and pass it to the View which would present it as html content.  What you would need for support is an edit button on the view which would go to the edit view and edit action, which would present the user an html textbox in which to edit the content.

The most comment html textbox you will see is [FreeTextBox](http://freetextbox.com/default.aspx).

Comment: Eric, i would like to know how can i show the html datas that i am storing it into the database to the user? I mean, how would i render to the user? on the click of the preview button i need to render that as an HTML below to the user. Does this FreeTextBox costs?

Comment: Well, you would store the content as html, so to display it, you would just need to add it to the DOM.  You could have a div setup that would act as a container and just set the tags conent to the database conent.  <div id="contentContainer"> <%= Html.Encode(ViewData["conent"]) %> - And yes the basic version of FreeTextBox is free.  There are plenty of html editors out there, do a google search and you'll find them.

Comment: Thanks eric,
Thanks for your suggesion,. let me try with this.

Answer (score 0):

If the ASP.NET MVC application is already built and you don't control the code...then no.

If you're building the application or have the ability to modify the code, then yes. You could make the solution as ellaborate as you'd like. You could even integrate the Telerik RADEditor to do the HTML editting.

Comment: Thanks justin,
Is the tool Telerik RADEditor freely available for download?

Comment: No. There is a license fee associated with use. I'm not sure which free alternatives are out there.